# Python and and or

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need a code that evaluates several rules to highlight some text and I'm having issues trying to understand how OR and AND works.

Rules:

```
if not text.endswith((".", "!", "?", "//", ":"))
if not bool(re.search('[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]', text)
if not text[0].isupper()
if not text[0] == "["
if not any(i in text[0] for i in ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]))
```

This is my current code:

```
elif (not text.endswith((".", "!", "?", "//", ":"))
    and not bool(re.search('[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]', text))
    or not text[0].isupper()
    or not text[0] == "["
    or not any(i in text[0] for i in ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"])):
    # highlight text
```

The first issue is obviously that I don't get when to use OR and when to use AND (despite checking the documentation).

As bonus issue: On my regex rule. It shouldn't highlight the text if it's only "33:44" but it should if a line is says "We are at 44:44 today" without the final dot. I don't know how to do that.

Also, I'd appreciate if the code could be simplified.

Comment: Use `or` if you want to continue if *either* condition is `True`, use `and` if you want to continue only if *both* conditions are `True`

Comment: What if I want a mix of both of them?

Comment: Then use a mix of `and` and `or`.  This doesn't seem to be a Python question so much as a programming question. I would read online about this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly. But if you

- want to match only a capital letter at the beginning of the string
- there can be digits of [0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] format in between
- the string should not end with any of the characters given

If this is the case, you can try with a simple regex pattern

```
import re
re.search(r"""(^[A-Z] #starting letter to be a upper case alphabet
      .*? #anything in between
      [0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] #digits of the given format
      .*? # anything again
      [^.!?//:]$ # none of these characters at the end
     )""", text, re.X)
```

You can modify the pattern as per your requirement.

Comment: Would that work if a sentence ends in just one / symbol? "This is a test/". I think it would fail, as I need it specifically with double slashes only. Also, missing sentences that start with the left bracket: [

Comment: Oops.Missed that! Yup, it wouldn't work for a single slash. Will update it soon